# ELK cluster user password

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

Firstly I create a single node ELK and I use this conig in my elasticsearch.yml

```
# sed '/^#/d' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
node.name: "elk01"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.security.enabled: true
discovery.type: single-node
```

after I use this command and create auto built-in users

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

and it's ok. Everything is working but I want elk-cluster. I create a new server and change config

elk01

```
# sed '/^#/d' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: "elk-testcluster"
node.name: "elk01"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.60.201.31", "10.60.201.32"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.60.201.31"]
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

elk02

```
# sed '/^#/d' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: "elk-testcluster"
node.name: "elk02"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.60.201.31", "10.60.201.32"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.60.201.31"]
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

Right now when I use curl with username/password, I can getting a elk01 but not elk02

```
# curl -XGET "10.60.201.31:9200" -u elastic:passcreatedonelk01
{
  "name" : "elk01",
  "cluster_name" : "elk-testcluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "7513Zor7S3SHqVFzs0hEMQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "79878662c54c886ae89206c685d9f1051a9d6411",
    "build_date" : "2022-05-18T18:04:20.964345128Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

# curl -XGET "10.60.201.32:9200" -u elastic:passcreatedonelk01
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}
```

When I create a new elasticsearch-setup-password on elk02, it's getting error.

```
 sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
Failed to determine the health of the cluster running at http://10.60.201.32:9200
Unexpected response code [503] from calling GET http://10.60.201.32:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Cause: master_not_discovered_exception

It is recommended that you resolve the issues with your cluster before running elasticsearch-setup-passwords.
It is very likely that the password changes will fail when run against an unhealthy cluster.

Do you want to continue with the password setup process [y/N]y

Initiating the setup of passwords for reserved users elastic,apm_system,kibana,kibana_system,logstash_system,beats_system,remote_monitoring_user.
The passwords will be randomly generated and printed to the console.
Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N]y



Unexpected response code [503] from calling PUT http://10.60.201.32:9200/_security/user/apm_system/_password?pretty
Cause: Cluster state has not been recovered yet, cannot write to the [null] index

Possible next steps:
* Try running this tool again.
* Try running with the --verbose parameter for additional messages.
* Check the elasticsearch logs for additional error details.
* Use the change password API manually.


ERROR: Failed to set password for user [apm_system].
```

When I make a cluster, is the use of a common password not provided? Or is it because I run an elasticsearch-setup-password before doing a cluster?

Comment: Hello can you show the output of these requests please ?
curl -XGET "10.60.201.31:9200/_cluster/health" -u elastic:passcreatedonelk01
curl -XGET "10.60.201.31:9200/_nodes" -u elastic:passcreatedonelk01

Comment: $ curl -XGET "10.60.201.31:9200/_cluster/health" -u elastic:passcreatedonelk01
{"cluster_name":"elk-testcluster","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":11,"active_shards":11,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}

Comment: In your cluster instead of having 2 nodes, you have only one elk01. It means the connetion between your nodes is fail (elk02 cannot discover elk01). Can you check in elk02 if there are errors in the logs ?

Comment: Yes, there is a error in /var/log/elasticsearch/elk-testcluster.log... [2022-07-07T10:09:01,105][WARN ][o.e.d.PeerFinder         ] [elk02] address [10.60.201.31:9300], node [null], requesting [false] connection failed: [][10.60.201.31:9300] general node connection failure: handshake failed because connection reset

Comment: put "xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled" at  "false" and restart all nodes

Comment: elk02 restart service but elk01 getting error like this Jul 07 12:41:48 elk01 systemd-entrypoint[764850]: ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
Jul 07 12:41:48 elk01 systemd-entrypoint[764850]: bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: Transport SSL must be enabled if security is enabled on a [basic] license. Please set [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] to [true] or disable security by setting [xpack.security.enabled] to [false]

Comment: ok i see the error, ssl must be enable. for a test i recommand you to ignore ssl verification and check if connection is done and after you can use your own certificate and key for ssl verification.

Comment: add these parameters "xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication: none" and "xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: none"

Comment: there is two error in two machine [elk01] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/10.60.201.31:9300, remoteAddress=/10.60.201.32:34310, profile=default}], closing connection...............[elk02] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/10.60.201.32:34570, remoteAddress=/10.60.201.31:9300, profile=default}], closing connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you enable ssl you need to add a certificate and key for each node for transport layer.

you can follow these instructions
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup.html

Comment: Yes, I was doing with this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhZqXvZmtiM) video and it's working right now. Thank for the all process.