# Kibana server is not ready yet & server down

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

a few days ago I asked a question about [elasticsearch xpack&cluster system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879964/elk-cluster-user-password). I solved this problem with  Paco and a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhZqXvZmtiM). Right now I have another question. My kibana is now working well.

elk01

```
# sed '/^#/d' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml 
cluster.name: "elk-testcluster"
node.name: "elk01"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.60.201.31", "10.60.201.32"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.60.201.31"]
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

elk02

```
# sed '/^#/d' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml 
cluster.name: "elk-testcluster"
node.name: "elk02"
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.60.201.31", "10.60.201.32"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.60.201.31"]
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

after I create a keepalived configuration and It's working very well.

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:e2:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.60.201.31/24 brd 10.60.201.255 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.60.201.30/24 scope global secondary ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:e2cd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My main goal is use cluster with single ip

```
# curl -XGET 'http://10.60.201.30:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' -u elastic:password1
{
  "cluster_name" : "elk-testcluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 13,
  "active_shards" : 24,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 92.3076923076923
}
```

and it's working well. But my problem is on kibana side.. it's not working and probably there is a small case I think.

First, I create a crt and key file with elastic-certificates.p12.

```
# ls -ltr
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kibana  305 May 18 11:21 node.options
-rw-rw---- 1 root kibana  130 Jun 20 10:12 kibana.keystore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kibana 3191 Jul 11 18:54 kibana.crt.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kibana 1853 Jul 11 18:55 kibana.key.pem
-rw-rw---- 1 root kibana 5294 Jul 11 19:04 kibana.yml
```

And I filled the configuration file.

```
# sed '/^#/d' kibana.yml 
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://10.60.201.31:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "pass1pass"
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/kibana.crt.pem
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/kibana.key.pem
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
```

I try this one is with 10.60.201.30 and localhost but it's not working. There is no error when I restart the service. But there is some line in /var/log/kibana/kibana.log

```
    {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:22:55+00:00","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":1616307,"message":"[Error: pickupUpdatedMappings task failed with the following failures:\n[{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"canvas-workpad-template:workpad-template-6181471b-147d-4397-a0d3-1c0f1600fa12\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"canvas-workpad-template:workpad-template-029bdeb3-40a6-4c90-9320-a5566abaf427\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"canvas-workpad-template:workpad-template-890b80e5-a3eb-431d-b8ed-37587ffd32c3\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"canvas-workpad-template:workpad-template-aefa8b2b-24ec-4093-8a59-f2cbc5f7c947\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"config:7.17.4\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"exception-list-agnostic:endpoint_trusted_apps\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"ingest_manager_settings:fleet-default-settings\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"osquery-manager-usage-metric:live_query\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"canvas-workpad-template:workpad-template-061d7868-2b4e-4dc8-8bf7-3772b52926e5\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"space:default\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"event_loop_delays_daily:71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53::675444::05072022\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"application_usage_daily:management:2022-07-05\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"ui-metric:kibana-user_agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"ui-metric:Kibana_home:welcomeScreenMount\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"application_usage_daily:home:2022-07-05\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"usage-counters:uiCounter:05072022:loaded:Kibana_home:welcomeScreenMount\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"event_loop_delays_daily:71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53::681885::05072022\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"event_loop_delays_daily:71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53::682398::05072022\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"event_loop_delays_daily:71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53::682398::06072022\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"spaces-usage-stats:spaces-usage-stats\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"core-usage-stats:core-usage-stats\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"telemetry:telemetry\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"event_loop_delays_daily:71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53::682398::07072022\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"apm-telemetry:apm-telemetry\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403}]\n    at /usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/actions/wait_for_pickup_updated_mappings_task.js:33:11\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Either.js:193:75\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Task.js:143:44\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at stateActionMachine (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/state_action_machine.js:67:28)\n    at migrationStateActionMachine (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/migrations_state_action_machine.js:92:24)\n    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n    at SavedObjectsService.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/saved_objects_service.js:181:9)\n    at Server.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/server.js:330:31)\n    at Root.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/root/index.js:69:14)\n    at bootstrap (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/bootstrap.js:120:5)\n    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/src/cli/serve/serve.js:229:5)]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:22:55+00:00","tags":["info","plugins-system","standard"],"pid":1616307,"message":"Stopping all plugins."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:22:55+00:00","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":1616307,"message":"Monitoring stats collection is stopped"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:22:55+00:00","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1616307,"message":"Error: pickupUpdatedMappings task failed with the following failures:\n[{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:data_enhanced_search_sessions_cleanup\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:endpoint:user-artifact-packager:1.0.0\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:data_enhanced_search_sessions_expire\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Actions-cleanup_failed_action_executions\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Alerts-alerts_invalidate_api_keys\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:session_cleanup\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:security:endpoint-diagnostics:1.0.0\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Alerting-alerting_health_check\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:data_enhanced_search_sessions_monitor\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:endpoint:metadata-check-transforms-task:0.0.1\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:security:endpoint-meta-telemetry:1.0.0\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:security:telemetry-detection-rules:1.0.0\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Alerting-alerting_telemetry\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Lens-lens_telemetry\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:Actions-actions_telemetry\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:security:telemetry-lists:1.0.0\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:apm-telemetry-task\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"id\":\"task:reports:monitor\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_7.17.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403}]\n    at /usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/actions/wait_for_pickup_updated_mappings_task.js:33:11\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Either.js:193:75\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Task.js:143:44\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at stateActionMachine (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/state_action_machine.js:67:28)\n    at migrationStateActionMachine (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/saved_objects/migrationsv2/migrations_state_action_machine.js:92:24)\n    at async Promise.all (index 1)"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:25+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins-system","standard"],"pid":1616307,"message":"\"eventLog\" plugin didn't stop in 30sec., move on to the next."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Plugin \"metricsEntities\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["info","http","server","Preboot"],"pid":1616560,"message":"http server running at https://0.0.0.0:5601"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"\"logging.dest\" has been deprecated and will be removed in 8.0. To set the destination moving forward, you can use the \"console\" appender in your logging configuration or define a custom one."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Starting in 8.0, the Kibana logging format will be changing. This may affect you if you are doing any special handling of your Kibana logs, such as ingesting logs into Elasticsearch for further analysis. If you are using the new logging configuration, you are already receiving logs in both old and new formats, and the old format will simply be going away. If you are not yet using the new logging configuration, the log format will change upon upgrade to 8.0. Beginning in 8.0, the format of JSON logs will be ECS-compatible JSON, and the default pattern log format will be configurable with our new logging system. Please refer to the documentation for more information about the new logging format."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Kibana is configured to authenticate to Elasticsearch with the \"kibana\" user. Use a service account token instead."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"The default mechanism for Reporting privileges will work differently in future versions, which will affect the behavior of this cluster. Set \"xpack.reporting.roles.enabled\" to \"false\" to adopt the future behavior before upgrading."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"User sessions will automatically time out after 8 hours of inactivity starting in 8.0. Override this value to change the timeout."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:38+00:00","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Users are automatically required to log in again after 30 days starting in 8.0. Override this value to change the timeout."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:39+00:00","tags":["info","plugins-system","standard"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Setting up [113] plugins: [translations,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,licenseApiGuard,code,usageCollection,xpackLegacy,taskManager,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,share,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,screenshotMode,banners,telemetry,newsfeed,mapsEms,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,fieldFormats,expressions,dataViews,charts,esUiShared,bfetch,data,savedObjects,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,customIntegrations,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,watcher,licenseManagement,advancedSettings,spaces,security,savedObjectsTagging,reporting,canvas,lists,ingestPipelines,fileUpload,encryptedSavedObjects,dataEnhanced,cloud,snapshotRestore,eventLog,actions,alerting,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,visualizations,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypePie,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,expressionTagcloud,expressionMetricVis,console,graph,fleet,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,dashboard,maps,dashboardMode,dashboardEnhanced,visualize,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,indexPatternFieldEditor,lens,cases,timelines,discover,osquery,observability,discoverEnhanced,dataVisualizer,ml,uptime,securitySolution,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,enterpriseSearch,apm,savedObjectsManagement,indexPatternManagement]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:39+00:00","tags":["info","plugins","taskManager"],"pid":1616560,"message":"TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: 71c330ef-1ef2-4b77-8cb8-de493473fe53"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-07-11T19:23:39+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":1616560,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command."}
```

Right now I see sometimes "Kibana server is not ready" sometimes web server down page (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

What do you think I am missing?

Comment: Before getting to Kibana, are you sure that Elasticsearch is fully functional? `"number_of_nodes" : 2` — from your config I would assume that there should be 3 nodes? Also `"unassigned_shards" : 2` is potentially not what you want.

Comment: No, there was 2 node. But there was 3 IP, one of my keepalived vip(10.60.201.30) others node ip (elk01 10.60.201.31 - elk02 10.60.201.32)

Comment: can you show the output of this request curl -XGET http://10.60.201.31:9200/_cluster/health/.kibana

Comment: {"cluster_name":"elk-testcluster","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":2,"number_of_data_nodes":2,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":2,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}